# How to fetch patent images from google BigQuery?

Tags: bigquery, images

I don't know how I can get the images for patent on Google Patent search.  I am using google's BigQuery but I don't see a table with the link to images.

Any ideas?

Comment: If i am not wrong and you are looking for patented images then, Images are not covered by patents they are protected by copyrights. If you are looking for images which are present in patents then you have to go through patent specifications

Comment: Is there a particular patent you are interested in? If so list it in the question.

Comment: thanks guys, I am new to this so what do you mean by patent specification? @RishiM_IPR?

Comment: The description part of patent which has drawings in it. Please specify what exactly your search is for

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you are really trying to do rather than just asking about how to get links to images?

Comment: I am trying to create a patent viewer into their app for a company and they want to be able to type in the patent number and show patent content and drawings